# onnxruntime-node in packaged electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, onnx, node.js-addon, onnxruntime

I'm using the onnxruntime-node package to do inferencing in my electron app. I installed the npm package via 'yarn add', and everything works as expected in development.

When I package the electron app, node isn't able to find the onnxruntime-node import.

In an attempt to solve this, I required the prebuild onnx runtime binaries instead.

```
const ort = require(path.join(`electron-app-dir\\node_modules\\onnxruntime-node\\bin\\napi-v3\\win32\\x64`,'onnxruntime_binding.node'));
```

This partially solves the problem, as node is able to find the prebuild binary, but I end up with a different error:

`'TypeError: ort.InferenceSession.create is not a function'`

I'm not sure now to proceed from here. There are some .dlls in the save directory as the onnxruntime_binding.node file. Do these need to be required as well?

Any help figured this out is appreciated!

For reference:

```
const ort = require(path.join(`electron-app-dir\\node_modules\\onnxruntime-node\\bin\\napi-v3\\win32\\x64`,'onnxruntime_binding.node'));

const modelPath =  path.join(__dirname,'model.onnx')

const session = await ort.InferenceSession.create(modelPath);

...
```

Comment: You don't have to require anything but the package itself (ie `const ort = require('onnxruntime-node`), however your bundler (Electron) will need to include the binary addon in the bundle.
Given your error message - `ort.InferenceSession` seem to be included. Try to extract the bundle to see if everything is there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can't reference the binaries directly. You always need to reference the node module directory.

I ended up just copying the `onnxruntime-node` module into the packaged app resources directory along with the binaries, which works.